# Swift @autoclosure broke compatibility in v1.2 for enum cases

Tags: xcode, swift

I just update Xcode to 6.3 and the Swift code that used to compile in Xcode 6.2 is not compiling now.

```
import Foundation

public enum Result<T> {
    case Success(@autoclosure() -> T)
    case Failure(NSError)
    case Cancelled

    public init(_ value: T) {
        self = .Success(value)
    }

    public init(_ error: NSError) {
        self = .Failure(error)
    }

    public init() {
        self = .Cancelled
    }

    public var failed: Bool {
        switch self {
        case .Failure(let error):
            return true

        default:
            return false
        }
    }

    public var error: NSError? {
        switch self {
        case .Failure(let error):
            return error

        default:
            return nil
        }
    }

    public var value: T? {
        switch self {
        case .Success(let value):
            return value()

        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

This line:
    `case Success(@autoclosure() -> T)`

yields an error: `'autoclosure' attribute is only allowed on parameters, not on enum cases`

Just removing `@autoclosure` doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Correct. This has been removed, explicitly to prevent the case you provide. Autoclosures were not intended to be used this way, and the Swift team intentionally removed the ability to do so. In a `Result` type, this is dangerous because the closure will be re-evalated every time it is accessed. If there are side-effects in the closure, this can have quite surprising impacts. Even if it's just non-trivial, it can have surprising performance impacts.

The correct tool here is `Box`. See Rob Rix's [`Result`](https://github.com/antitypical/Result/blob/master/Result/Result.swift) for a good implementation of this type.

Comment: We had decided to try Swift on some of our products but if we have unexpected syntax breaks from one version to another it's a deal breaker. Specially if it comes without a deprecation first.

Comment: Swift may not be appropriate for your product in that case. It is still under development, and while stabilizing, you should expect more breaks in the future.

Comment: I just think it could have a migration guide as Python did when they moved from 2 to 3

Comment: It could, but it won't for the next several releases at a minimum. You should plan accordingly.

Comment: I suppose there's no way to inform Xcode 6.3 to use the older Swift version ?

Comment: No. Swift is ever-forward (like almost all Apple technology).

Comment: @RobNapier So swift is ever-broken too?

Comment: I was using a very similar approach to Result and somehow I am reluctant to replace this rather simple standalone enum Type by Rob Rix's implementation with a dependency on two more frameworks. Did anybody find a simpler solution without the requirement of dependencies?

Comment: LlamaKit is a single-file solution. I've discontinued support in favor of Rib Rix's solution (despite its additional requirements; it actually requires a total of 4 frameworks ultimately). But LlamaKit has almost the same interface, and should continue to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think that I have found the solution. You only need to change 2 lines in your original implementation to make it work:

```
case Success(() -> T)
```

And

```
public init(@autoclosure(escaping) _ value: () -> T) {
```

Comment: @Pablo, it works for me, what kind of error do you get?

Comment: Autoclosure is not allowed as a parameter

Comment: @Pablo, you are right - I've made a mistake: the param should be of closure type "() -> T" instead of just "T". I have updated my answer, please try it.

Answer (score 0):

For those who only want a simply solution without having to import external frameworks:

```
public enum Result<T> {

  case Success(Box<T>)
  case Failure(String)

  public init(_ value: T) {
      self = .Success(Box(value))
  }

  public init(_ error: String) {
      self = .Failure(error)
  }

}

// Due to current swift limitations, we have to include this Box in Result.
final public class Box<T> {
    public let unbox: T
    public init(_ value: T) { self.unbox = value }
}

public func success<T>(value: T) -> Result<T> {
    return .Success(Box(value))
}

public func failure<T>(error: String) -> Result<T> {
    return .Failure(error)
}
```