# Converting Swift convenience initializer to Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, closures

I need to convert the following `convenience` initializer from Swift to Objective-C

```
    convenience init(view: UIView, overlapHandler: (CGRect)->()) {
        self.init(view: view, handler: { overlap -> () in
            overlapHandler(overlap ?? CGRect.nullRect)
        })
    }
```

My first attempt was:

```
-(instancetype) initWithView:(UIView*)view overlapHandler:(Handler)handler
{
    Handler overlapHandler = ^(CGRect overlap) {
        if (CGRectIsNull(overlap)) {
            return;
        }
        handler(overlap);
    };
    return [self initWithView:view andHandler:overlapHandler];
}
```

But it didn't work well as I don't see how an Objective-C block can receive a non-optional CGRect.

The context of the code is below:

```
import UIKit

class KeyboardOverlapNotifier:NSObject {
    typealias Handler = (CGRect?) -> ()

    let view:UIView
    let handler:Handler

    init(view:UIView, handler:Handler) {
        self.view = view
        self.handler = handler
        super.init()
        beginListening()
    }

    deinit {
        stopListening()
    }

    func beginListening() {
        token = token ?? nc.addObserverForName(UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, 
                             object:nil, queue:nil, usingBlock:keyboardFrameDidChange)
    }

    func stopListening() {
        if let observer = token {
            nc.removeObserver(observer)
            token = nil
        }
    }

    private let nc:NSNotificationCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
    private var token:NSObjectProtocol?
}

private extension KeyboardOverlapNotifier {
    func keyboardFrameDidChange(notification: NSNotification!) {
        let duration = notification.userInfo!
             [UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as NSTimeInterval

        UIView.animateWithDuration(duration,
            delay: 0,
            options: .BeginFromCurrentState,
            animations: {
                let keyboard:CGRect = {
                    let global = (notification.userInfo!
                     [UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as NSValue).CGRectValue()
                    let local = self.view.convertRect(global, fromView: nil)
                    return local
                }()
                let overlap = self.view.bounds.rectByIntersecting(keyboard)
                self.handler(overlap.nonEmptyOrNil)
            },
            completion: nil)
    }
}

extension KeyboardOverlapNotifier {
    convenience init(view: UIView, overlapHandler: (CGRect)->()) {
        self.init(view: view, handler: { overlap -> () in
            overlapHandler(overlap ?? CGRect.nullRect)
        })
    }
}

extension CGRect {
    var nonEmptyOrNil:CGRect? { return !self.isEmpty ? self : nil }
}
```

Comment: I'm curious, what is unstable? I have converted all my apps to Swift and haven't found anything "unstable". Perhaps the compiler could use some enhancements for some scenarios but I haven't found anything to be unstable. My fear is you will convert everything back to ObjC just to want to convert it all back to PROPER Swift code in the near future. I would say fix the Swift code vs replacing it.

Comment: check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29539812/swift-autoclosure-broke-compatibility-in-v1-2-for-enum-cases

Comment: That has nothing to do with "unstable". Swift 1.2 is _vastly_ better than any preceding version. Learn how it works; don't walk backwards just because you feel a little surprised with the changes.

Comment: @matt even Apple is not using it widely as you can see in the ResearchKit source code.

Comment: No, just no... There are inherent differences between what was discussed on that other use case vs this. Claiming Swift is unstable is pure ignorance(no offense). That's like saying since Microsoft has some native C code in their software so nobody should use C#. There are vast differences here and each needs to be understood to be used properly. Swift was actually written for this exact reason... To correct limitations and enhance usability. And trust me when I say, Apple uses a LOT of Swift... That's why I ask, Which part of your code is unstable?

Comment: @DCGoD let's not turn it into a *fundamentalist* war. Unstable means that there's no guarantee that we'll have deprecations before the syntax changes breaking backwards compatibility.

Comment: Did ObjC ever offer a guarantee on deprecation? You're headed down a squirrelly path here... Nobody is trying to argue here for sure, we are just trying to share some experience. The choice is definitely yours to make.

Comment: Syntax changes do not break anything, because Swift is not _in the system_. It is _in the app_. The app continues to work, once built, even if Swift changes later - because the version of Swift with which the app was built is _baked into the app itself_.

Comment: @ppaulojr It is perfectly fine to write in Objective-C, in Swift, or both. There is no fundamentalism about that. Many of my apps are now hybrids. Swift has some clear disadvantages (for one thing, its speed is suspect). But _your_ reasons for claiming that Swift is "unstable" and that _therefore_ you need to rewrite in Objective-C are just plug-ignorant and flat-out false.

Comment: @matt it just stopped compiling. And I don't want to learn Swift by now and we decided to get rid of all swift code. That was my question, pure and simple.

Comment: No, your question says "as it turned out that Swift is still unstable". That is not "pure and simple". If that isn't what you meant to say, then edit your question so that it doesn't say that.

Comment: "it just stopped compiling" And you asked why and you got good answers. All you had to do was listen and change the code accordingly.

Comment: @matt to please the Swift developers I've changed the wording. I don't want to fix compilation I want to remove Swift. Is it forbidden to remove swift?

Comment: Check my answer and you'll understand how to remove Swift for this one case. And no, feel freely to remove Swift along with other's advice. In the end the only important thing is understanding what you're removing so you can translate it back to ObjC if you absolutely must.

Comment: Okay, so now what's the question? You just want to know how to write `convenience init(view: UIView, overlapHandler: (CGRect)->()) {` in Objective-C? You want to write it (declare it)? Or call it? Or both? Please eliminate the extra stuff and focus on the actual question.

Comment: @matt I just wanted to write it in Objective-C, I don't want a war on Swift. I understand that many of you guys are working hard on swift: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920034278.do and I respect it.

Comment: I have edited the question to reflect a business decision and not pass judgement on the language.

Comment: But you have not edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: @matt I have edited to try to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this should help? I'm still unsure what your question actually is so the only thing I can offer is references to each.

*Closures are self-contained blocks of functionality that can be passed around and used in your code. Closures in Swift are similar to blocks in C and Objective-C and to lambdas in other programming languages.
Closures can capture and store references to any constants and variables from the context in which they are defined. This is known as closing over those constants and variables, hence the name “closures”. Swift handles all of the memory management of capturing for you.*

[Blocks vs Closures](http://fuckingswiftblocksyntax.com)

https://www.codefellows.org/blog/writing-completion-blocks-with-closures-in-swift

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html

Comment: I was not the one who downvoted you. BTW: I was downvoted too

Comment: No worries. My advice, find the exact area of concern and create a new question. This horse can't be beaten anymore... FYI, I don't hate ObjC and I don't love Swift (well maybe ;-)) but the point is they are simply different ways to tell the compiler what you want to do. The underlying result on the device is the key. Both can obtain rock solid results.

Comment: I found the guy who downvoted you in the office and I asked him to remove it.

Comment: LMAO, sorry that's funny to me. Please please please don't think anyone here is trying to be a PITA. We are simply trying to steer you in the right direction. We have ALL done code conversions and if I've learned anything about Swift so far it's that if I think Swift can't do it, I simply do not know how to do it in Swift yet. But EVERY TIME I learned the new technique I never looked back at ObjC... FYI, matt is one of the most knowledgable members here in the iOS community. I'm amazed he is still here helping others nearly full-time. Heed his advice. Good luck!